Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \cos^nx \, dx$ without using newton leibniz
I'm asked to calculate:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \cos^n x \, dx, 
$$

So far I have reached this:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \cos^n x \, dx 
= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n-1}{n} \int_0^1 \cos^{n-2}x \, dx,
$$
but I don't know how to proceed from here. I'm given a hint that I should look at the integral over $[0, 1]$ as a sum of integrals over $[0, \epsilon]$ and $[\epsilon, 1]$. I have no idea how I could use it.

I assume this has to be solved without relying on Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?

Have any suspicion about what the answer is? You can’t do this by actually calculating the integral.

Hint: On $[\varepsilon, 1]$, you can use that $\cos^n(x)$ has a very simple limit as $n\to \infty$. For the integral over $[0,\varepsilon]$, you can use the smallness of the domain of integration and the boundedness of $\cos^n(x)$.

@Gonçalo that does, thank you everybody
